# Spring JPA group by query pageable injects unnecessary ID causes syntax error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to use Spring Data Pageable with JPA Query (Not native) which cases the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Expression #1 of ORDER BY clause is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'alerting.alerthisto0_.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

Here is my query:

```
@Query(value =
      "SELECT history.alertId AS alertId, history.userId AS userId, alert.organization.id AS organizationId,"
          + " alert.status AS status, alert.createdAt AS createdAt, COUNT(history.alertId) AS alertsCount"
          + " FROM AlertHistory AS history LEFT JOIN Alert AS alert ON history.alertId=alert.id"
          + " GROUP BY history.alertId, history.userId")
  Page<AlertAggregationDetails> groupByAlertIdAndUserId(Pageable pageable);
```

Apparently, because I am using Pageable `history.id` is injected which is unnecessary and causing syntax issue. If I add history.id to the `group by` section the syntax will be correct but obviously, the result is far from what I'd like to have. I was wondering if there is a way to fix the syntax issue and continue using Pageable.

Also, if I remove Pageable this query works and there is no issue.

**EDIT:**

After I debug the query I noticed that Spring JPA added `ORDER BY history.id` to my query automatically when I use `Pageable`. As a workaround, I can replace `sql_mode`, but I don't understand why I cannot overwrite `ORDER BY` with Pageable.

Comment: Can you tell us which spring version you are using? I tried this query and this worked just fine.

Comment: @Shawrup I am using Spring boot 2.1.7

Comment: How are you creating your Pageable object ? You might have added sort in pageable.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK Spring Data by default adds the entity id as order by expression if you don't add any sorts which might be what you see. It makes sense, because you want a consistent ordering, otherwise pagination wouldn't work. You will have to add the sorts `alertId` and `userId` for MySQL to be happy and also get consistent results.